# Python 2D array manipulation

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and want to use 2D array
To copy a 2D array I can use deepcopy but I was wondering (to do more complex thing ) why this code doesn't copy my 2D array

```
a = [[0] * 10, [1] * 10, [2] * 10]
b = [[0] * 10] * 3

for j in range(10):

    for i in range(3):
        t = a[i][j]
        s = b[i][j]
        b[i][j] = a[i][j]
print b

>>> b
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) is a great tool to help with debugging. You can set a breakpoint with `pdb.set_trace()` after importing pdb and it will let you step through the code execution to determine what is occurring. I highly recommend you take a look at it.

Over here, if you set the breakpoint within the inner for loop, you will see that on each run, it will modify all the lists. They share the same memory address as the answer below mentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first duplication works, because integers are immutable, so they always get copied.

```
x = [0] * 10
```

However, the situation is different with the lists. What's actually stored in the list is just a reference, which gets copied. That's why all the lists in B are the same.

```
y = [x] * 3
y[0] is y[1]
>>> True
```

To achieve your original goal, explicitly copy each of the lists. You can use slicing for that :

```
y = [t[:] for t in y]
y[0] is y[1]
>>> False
```

Comment: Its not because integers are primitive types, but because they are immutable.

Comment: And primitive types are immutable. However, I edited the answer to make it more general.

Comment: @BartoszKP How can you modify that? Can you give an example?

Comment: In fact, integers ARE immutable. Just the fact that you can assign an immutable instance to a variable doesn't make it mutable. Just try `x = 1; id(x); x += 1; id(x)` - the ids are different.

Comment: A nice overview of the topic can be found here : http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: While the answer is good, I would personally use the constructor `list(t)` instead of slicing `t[:]`. It's more expressive.

Comment: @ChirilaAlexandru: It's a bit more expressive, but also a bit slower.